# strict mode typescript checks fails from tsconfig.json

Tags: typescript, tsconfig, strict

I have a simple typing error detected with cli flag `--strict`

```
$ ./node_modules/.bin/tsc --strict main.ts
main.ts:6:5 - error TS2322: Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'Person'.

6     return null;
      ~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

When I try to put the `strict` flag inside `tsconfig.json` it doesn't work:

```
$ cat tsconfig.json
{ "compilerOptions": { "strict": true } }
$ ./node_modules/.bin/tsc main.ts
$ # no typing errors found
```

The actual source code is (probably) irrelevant, but for completeness reasons:

```
class Person {
  constructor(private lastName: string){}

  public getFriend(name: string): Person {
    if (name == "Someone") { return new Person("Mr."); }
    return null;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In `tsconfig` that's `strictNullChecks`

Comment: "strict": true implicitly enables strictNullChecks; specifying strictNullChecks in the tsconfig also does not aid this error.